# csp-report endpoint in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm trying to set up CSP in an asp.net core webapp, and the CSP part works fine, I can see the violations in the browser console as they are sent to the  report-uri endpoint.

However, I cannot seem to create the correct method in a controller to receive these messages!

I create a method in the controller as:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public IActionResult UriReport(CspReportRequest request)
{
    _log.LogError("CSP violation: " + request);
    return Ok();
}
```

and it will be called, but the 'request' parameter is always null. Some searching reveals that I need to use the [FromBody] attribute to read the data from the body, but once I put that in, it no longer gets called.
*(CspReportRequest is a class with properties matching the csp-report payload, but it doesn't work with string type either.)*

So further reading suggests I add a handler for the 'application/csp-report' content-type that the body is being sent as:

```
services.Configure<MvcOptions>(options => {
    options.InputFormatters.OfType<JsonInputFormatter>().First().SupportedMediaTypes.Add(
        new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/csp-report"));
});
```

But this doesn't seem to make a difference.

So - how do I make the correct controller signature, and/or the correct service handler options to receive the data.

Comment: You could try [NWebsec libraries](https://docs.nwebsec.com/en/latest/nwebsec/libraries.html). And you could refer discussion on [Add support for content security policy #6001](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/6001)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two things required to make this work. The first is adding `[FromBody]` to your `CspReportRequest request` parameter<sup>1</sup>:

```
public IActionResult UriReport([FromBody] CspReportRequest request)
```

Without `[FromBody]`, the `JsonInputFormatter` will not be used to parse the request body. However, *with* `[FromBody]`, you're going to start seeing `415` responses.

The second thing is configuring the `JsonInputFormatter` to support the `application/csp-report` media-type, which you've already attempted to do. The problem with your approach is that there are actually *two* instances of `JsonInputFormatter` configured, and you're affecting the wrong one. If you just change from `First()` to `Last()`<sup>2</sup>, it should work.

Why? The first `JsonInputFormatter` in the collection is actually an instance of [`JsonPatchInputFormatter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.formatters.jsonpatchinputformatter?view=aspnetcore-2.2), which extends `JsonInputFormatter`:

> ```
> public class JsonPatchInputFormatter : JsonInputFormatter
> ```

This gets added first and so it's the one you're configuring. It can't process an instance of `CspReportRequest` because it has specific rules about handling `JsonPatchDocument<T>`, etc, so it passes on to the second `JsonInputFormatter`. This second instance isn't configured to support `application/csp-report`, as I've mentioned, so it also can't handle the request.

---

<sup>1</sup> If you're using `[ApiController]`, you won't need to use `[FromBody]`, but everything from your question suggests that you're not using `[ApiController]`.

<sup>2</sup> Using `Last()` instead of `First()` isn't necessarily the best approach here, but it should demonstrate where the problem lies. There are many ways to get the specific `JsonInputFormatter` you are interested in.

Answer (score 1):

```
        .AddMvcOptions(options => {
            options.InputFormatters.OfType<NewtonsoftJsonInputFormatter>()
                .First(f => f.SupportedMediaTypes.Contains("application/json"))
                .SupportedMediaTypes.Add("application/csp-report");
        });
```

There might be not `JsonInputFormatter` but `NewtonsoftJsonInputFormatter` if you use `.AddNewtonsoftJson()`

Also, take note of the First predicate. The point is that there are several formatters that inherit from `JsonInputFormatter` (one for patch), and you are interested in that one that already supports `application/json`

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to read the Request.Body to get the report.

Don't forget to include the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc namespace.

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Report()
{
    var report = "";

    using (var reader = new StreamReader(Request.Body))
    {
        report = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
            
    _log.LogError("CSP violation: " + report);
    return Ok();
}
```

The report variable will contain the json report data.