# Allow "application/csp-report" mediatype header in mvc 5

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, content-security-policy, .net-4.8

I have a asp.net mvc 5 (not core) application where I want to allow media type `application/csp-report`. All the help is related to either .net core or web api but I want to allow it in mvc 5 application. How can I do that?

I've an endpoint in my applicaiton that is require to have `application/csp-report` enabled otherwise I am getting null in the request model. The app is targeting .net framework 4.8.

I want to do same like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57146684/csp-report-endpoint-in-asp-net-core) but in .net framework app

Answer (score 1):

Below code block can help you:

```
Request.InputStream.Position = 0;
            using (StreamReader inputStream = new StreamReader(Request.InputStream))
            {
                string s = inputStream.ReadToEnd();
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s))
                {
                    CspPost cspPost = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CspPost>(s);
                    //now you can access properties of cspPost.CspReport
                }
            }


public class CspPost
    {
        [JsonProperty("csp-report")]
        public CspReport CspReport { get; set; }
    }

    public class CspReport
    {
        [JsonProperty("document-uri")]
        public string DocumentUri { get; set; }
        public string referrer { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("violated-directive")]
        public string ViolatedDirective { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("effective-directive")]
        public string EffectiveDirective { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("original-policy")]
        public string OriginalPolicy { get; set; }
        public string disposition { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("blocked-uri")]
        public string BlockedUri { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("line-number")]
        public int LineNumber { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("column-number")]
        public int ColumnNumber { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("source-file")]
        public string SourceFile { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("status-code")]
        public int StatusCode { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("script-sample")]
        public string ScriptSample { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).